# Finding mongodb data within a certain period

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am currently trying to show certain data from a mongo db.

I have a frontend where 2 dates will be selected, and when a button is hit, it sends a request to my node server, with those 2 dates
i then want it to only select data within these 2 dates

How would i pull this off? I already have dates linked to each data.

Dates are stored in MomentJS full string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) properties to query a collection using a date range, e.g.

```
db.collection.find({ date: { $gte: now, $lte: futureDate  } })
```

Comment: What if i have more than just "date" set in that query? how would i manage to pull that?

Comment: You can just add another property to your query, like so: ```db.collection.find({ date: { $gte: now, $lte: futureDate  }, title: 'This is the title' })```